# Getting SyntaxError for working code that uses os.popen()

Tags: python, regex, linux

I am writing a Python script to test my CS50 assignment by extracting, executing, and comparing against commands extracted from a string. The commands themselves work and produce results; however, that doesn't seem to be the case when called using `os.popen()` or other Python bash callers, and it ends up producing a `SyntaxError`.

The Code:

```
import os
import re

with open("makefile", "r") as file:
    data = file.read()
    data = re.split("\n", data, re.M)
    for argument in data:
        i = 0
        pattern = re.compile(r'(?:as\s)(python\sdna.py\sdatabases/[a-zA-Z]+\.csv\ssequences/[0-9]+\.txt)')
        command = pattern.finditer(argument)
        namept = re.compile(r'(No\s)?[a-zA-Z]+\.$')
        name = namept.search(argument)
        name = name.group(0).replace(".", "")
        for arg in command:
            command = arg.group(1)
        stream = os.popen(command)
        output = stream.read()
        if output != name:
            print("error at", i)
        i += 1
```

The Make File:

```
Run your program as python dna.py databases/small.csv sequences/1.txt. Your program should output Bob.
Run your program as python dna.py databases/small.csv sequences/2.txt. Your program should output No match.
Run your program as python dna.py databases/small.csv sequences/3.txt. Your program should output No match.
Run your program as python dna.py databases/small.csv sequences/4.txt. Your program should output Alice.
Run your program as python dna.py databases/large.csv sequences/5.txt. Your program should output Lavender.
Run your program as python dna.py databases/large.csv sequences/6.txt. Your program should output Luna.
Run your program as python dna.py databases/large.csv sequences/7.txt. Your program should output Ron.
Run your program as python dna.py databases/large.csv sequences/8.txt. Your program should output Ginny.
Run your program as python dna.py databases/large.csv sequences/9.txt. Your program should output Draco.
Run your program as python dna.py databases/large.csv sequences/10.txt. Your program should output Albus.
Run your program as python dna.py databases/large.csv sequences/11.txt. Your program should output Hermione.
Run your program as python dna.py databases/large.csv sequences/12.txt. Your program should output Lily.
Run your program as python dna.py databases/large.csv sequences/13.txt. Your program should output No match.
Run your program as python dna.py databases/large.csv sequences/14.txt. Your program should output Severus.
Run your program as python dna.py databases/large.csv sequences/15.txt. Your program should output Sirius.
Run your program as python dna.py databases/large.csv sequences/16.txt. Your program should output No match.
Run your program as python dna.py databases/large.csv sequences/17.txt. Your program should output Harry.
Run your program as python dna.py databases/large.csv sequences/18.txt. Your program should output No match.
Run your program as python dna.py databases/large.csv sequences/19.txt. Your program should output Fred.
Run your program as python dna.py databases/large.csv sequences/20.txt. Your program should output No match.
```

The error:

```
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
error at 0
  File "dna.py", line 34
    regex = re.findall(f'(?:{cats})+', sequence)
                                    ^
```

dna.py

```
from sys import argv, exit
import csv
import re

if len(argv) != 3:
    print("missing argument. usage: python dna.py [DATABASE] [SEQUENCE]")
    exit(1)

database = argv[1]
sequence = argv[2]

with open(database, "r") as file:
    literal = list()
    data = [dict()]
    csv_reader = csv.reader(file, delimiter=",")
    for row in csv_reader:
        literal = row.copy()
        break
    file.seek(0)
    csv_reader = csv.DictReader(file)
    for row in csv_reader:
        data.append(row)
    data.pop(0)

iteration = dict()
for item in literal:
    iteration.update({item: 0})

with open(sequence, "r") as file:
    csv_reader = csv.reader(file)
    for row in csv_reader:
        sequence = "".join(row)
    for cats in literal:
        regex = re.findall(f'(?:{cats})+', sequence)
        res = 0 if not regex else round(len(max(regex)) / len(cats))
        iteration[cats] = res

for i in range(len(data)):
    error = 0
    for cats in literal:
        if cats != 'name':
            if int(data[i][cats]) != iteration[cats]:
                error += 1
    if error is 0:
        iteration['name'] = data[i]['name']
        break
    else:
        iteration['name'] = "No Match"

print(iteration['name'])
```

Note that the commands extracted with REGEX work when I copy it myself to the terminal.

Comment: `regex = re.findall(f'(?:{cats})+', sequence)` does not appear in the posted code...

Comment: that goes in the "dna.py" file

Comment: @JohnGordon edited the post

Comment: f-strings (i.e. a string that begins with `f"..."`) are supported only in Python version 3.6 or later.  What version of Python are you using?

Comment: @JohnGordon Python 3.7.9

Comment: Hmm.  Can you show the output of `import sys; print(sys.version)`?

Comment: Python 3.7.9 (default, Nov 30 2020, 02:19:40) 
[GCC 7.5.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import sys
>>> print(sys.version)
3.7.9 (default, Nov 30 2020, 02:19:40) 
[GCC 7.5.0]

Comment: That line of code works fine for me, on Python 3.6.9.  When I run that code on Python 2.7, I get that exact error message.  How are you running this code?  Are you just running `python myscript.py` on the command line?

Comment: Okay, so I got the error fixed when I explicitly changed the command string to call `python3` instead of `python`. Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

So the problem with the code ended up being the lack of support for formatted strings in Python 2.x.x despite the fact that this code is called from within Python 3.7.9. To get around this, I had to separate my regex calls into groups so that I can change `python`to `python3`. The new code looks something like this:

```
pattern = re.compile(r'(?:as\s)(python)(\sdna.py\sdatabases/[a-zA-Z]+\.csv\ssequences/[0-9]+\.txt)')

for arg in command:
            command = arg.group(1) + "3" + arg.group(2)
```